# Finding the boundary of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $I$ be any interval in the real line and consider the set $A = I \cap \mathbb{Q} $.Notice $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q} $. then $A$ must have measure zero since $\mathbb{Q}$ does. Is the boundary of $A$ the interval $I$ ??? If so, how can I prove this? thanks

Comment: There is no direct relation between 'measure 0' and 'boundary'.

Comment: I am trying to show that the boundary of $A$ does not have measure zero

Comment: The boundary of the set $A$ is its closure without its interior. In your case, it is the interval $I$ minus the empty set, thus the boundary is exactly $I$ which has a positive measure.

Comment: @tetori: measure $0$ implies that the complement is dense, so the boundary equals closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. The boundary of $A$ is equal to $\overline{A}\cap \overline{\Bbb{R}-A}$. Check that $\overline{A}=I$ and $\Bbb{R}-A$ is dense in $I$.